# Linux oom killer - find fragmented process

Tags: process, arm, out-of-memory, debian-based, memory-fragmentation

I am currently facing major issues with OOM after upgrading from Debian 7 to Debian 8 on arm (cubietruck).
I have already read a lot about oom mechanism and causes, still I miss an answer to

How to find memory fragmentation of a running process?

I have cat-ed /proc/buddyinfo and see fragmentation raise till the moment where oom kills a process. But this is only for the whole system. Is there a possibility to get buddyinfo like information on a per process base?

P.S.: I assume some process creates (via kmalloc?) fragmentation or by its run-time behavior triggering actions in the kernel that fragments memory (buffers, control structures or whatever ...)

---

The **cubietruck** system has 2GB RAM and 4GB swap.

```
   
2017-03-16 09:06:17 cubietruck kernel:[2114250.857191] 
HighMem free:245388kB min:512kB low:2016kB high:3520kB 
active_anon:200864kB 
inactive_anon:230728kB 
active_file:331288kB 
inactive_file:294800kB 
unevictab le:0kB 
writepending:0kB 
present:1307648kB 
managed:1307648kB 
mlocked:0kB 
slab_reclaimable:0kB 
slab_unreclaimable:0kB 
kernel_stack:0kB 
pagetables:2456kB 
bounce:0kB 
free_pcp:92kB 
local_pcp:0kB 
free_cma:0kB 
lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 0
```

Comment: You are mixing some concepts.  The kernel is never involve in *user* memory fragmentation.  There are possible kernel fragmentation issues where `/proc/buddyinfo` may be useful, but it is not for user space.  The OOM killer is invoked when the total request from user space is greater than swap+core memory.  The physical memory (kmalloc) maybe fragmented, but it is given a virtual address (via `sbrk` and friends) so that a process never gets fragmented memory from the kernel.  Also, physically fragmented memory is fine to give to user space.  So your issue is just to find user space tasks.

Comment: @artless-noise: What I see in syslog when oom kills a process is, that from 4GB swap only 50MB are used. So more swap will not help.
In addition I see for the two memory zones HighMem free 380MB and Normal 3.5MB. So maybe the question is rather _how to find processes that eat up memory from the Normal zone_...
I know that userspace vmallocs should not be affected by fragmentation due to virtualization of the physical memory. That's why I suspect some kernel internals.
I will try to disable memory overcommit and see the results it has on the system.

Comment: @artless-noise: I finally had a chance again to further debug my system. 
I have 2GB RAM (cubietruck) and 4GB swap.
OOM killer reports right before it kills a process:

Comment: I then narrowed it down to /etc/cron.daily/locate. When adding my storage backup directory (3.2M dirs & files) to the prune path I have no more issue with OOM. 
So it seems it is an issue with find and updatedb. Any idea where to search next?

Comment: You should add this information to the question.  It is possible that some 'disk' driver has an issue with memory.  It may also be an issue with the file system you are using.  JFFS, UbiFS, etc.  Accessing the files will fill the Linux disk cache, which may also have a bug.  Normally it would not affect memory.  I would identify the operation/command and create some other file systems and see if the conditions persists or goes away with a different FS.